# how to get all number from beginning of string until first non-number?

Tags: javascript

How to get all number from beginning of string until first non-number?

For example, I want to get 12345 from '12345abc' and another example get 5678 from '5678kkk'.

Is any way can do this?

Comment: What did you try before asking? Could you post code please?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `RegExp#match` with `^` anchor, to find out the numeric characters from beginning:

```js
const string = "12345abc";
const matches = string.match(/^\d+/);

// Fallback if no matches found
const numbers = (matches || [])[0];

console.log(numbers);
```

Comment: +1 for the most versatile solution. parseInt will help for this specific situation, but it is useless when you want to get the numbers at the end of a string, for example. However, if you want to prevent a TypeError when the string cannot be matched, modify the statement like so: ("12345abc".match(/^\d+/) || [])[0]

Comment: @Delvian -- thanks for pointing out. Comment addressed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseInt()` as it will stripe out all the characters other than the numeric character so you do not need custom logic for getting the numeric value as you have described:

```js
console.log(parseInt('12345abc'));
```

> The parseInt() function parses a string argument and returns an integer of the specified radix (the base in mathematical numeral systems).

Comment: omg, I am such a idiot. This seems so simple but I just know it until now. Appreciated!

Comment: @Dreams that's ok. Glad to help you.

Comment: @Dreams Just be aware this will make it into a valid number, eg. `01234` would become `1234`, IOW: you will loose the 0 at the start, depending on what you need the number for this might be fine, but if it was say to get a telephone No., it wouldn't..

Answer (score 0):

Use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

```js
let str = '5678kkk';

console.log(parseInt(str));
```

Comment: Thanks. I just know it until now.

Comment: @Dreams - Enjoy the new learning  applies to everyone :) Happy to help you!

Comment: Usually a good idea to include the radix..